# Is there a way to flag cookies as HttpOnly in Pylons?

Tags: cookies, pylons, httponly

I can't find any documentation on the web about how to do this.  I think its probably possible to send some sort of custom HTTP header response, but it seems kind of lame to do that if there is a more canonical way.

Answer (score 1):

```
theresponse.set_cookie(..., httponly=True, ...)
```